# how to make it tinter OOP?

Tags: python-3.x, function, user-interface, tkinter

I am having trouble making my procedural code into OOP.

```
#-----create the grid--------------------------
i=0
for employee in range(len(Employees)+1):
    for day in range(len(Days)+1):
        self.label = tk.Label(self, relief="ridge", width=13, 
        height=3)
        self.label.grid(row=employee, column=day, )

        if i < len(the_list) and employee>0 and day>0 and employee +                           
                day >=2:
                self.label['text'] = str(the_list[i])
                i += 1
```

the above code is procedural and it works with the output that i wanted.

my problem is how can I put the list into the grid labels by pushing the "calculate" problem?  I don't know how to make it OOP with the indentation from procedural.

here is the complete code

```
import tkinter as tk


Days= ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday",    
"Saturday", "Sunday"]
the_list = ["North", "Central", "East", "West", "Central", "South",   
"North"]
Employees=["Truck A"]

new_list = {}
labeldays={}
labelemployee={}



class Application():

    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.main_window=parent

        self.top_frame=tk.Frame(self.main_window, bg="PaleGreen2")
        self.top_frame.pack()
        self.bottom_frame=tk.Frame(self.main_window, bg="gray",)
        self.bottom_frame.pack(side="bottom", fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):


#-----create the grid--------------------------
        i=0
        for employee in range(len(Employees)+1):
            for day in range(len(Days)+1):
                self.label = tk.Label(self, relief="ridge", width=13, 
                height=3)
                self.label.grid(row=employee, column=day, )

                if i < len(the_list) and employee>0 and day>0 and 
                employee + day >=2:
                        self.label['text'] = str(the_list[i])
                        i += 1

#------add in the weekday name labels------------------
        i=1
        for day in Days:
            self.label=tk.Label(self, text=day,  fg="red", bg="snow")
            self.label.grid(row=0, column=i)
            labeldays[day]=self.label
            i +=1

#--------add in name labels on the side--------------
        i=1
        for employee in Employees:
            self.label=tk.Label(self, text=employee,  fg="red",   
            bg="snow")
            self.label.grid(row=i,column=0)
            labelemployee[employee]=self.label
            i +=1

        self.closeButton = tk.Button(self.bottom_frame,    
        text="CALCULATE", command=put_in_the_grid)
        self.closeButton.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.okButton = tk.Button(self.bottom_frame, text="QUIT",   
        command=self._destroy)
        self.okButton.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

    def _destroy(self):
        self.main_window.destroy()


def main():

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("class basic window")
    root.geometry("1000x300")
    root.config(background="LightBlue4")
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the reason i want to do this is because I created a button that will take the value of a list and put into the grid label that i created. the button will execute  "def put_in_the_grid(self):" keeping the grid label. [image] I don't know is it an inheritance issue, or a "self" issue.  if it is, where is the "self" argument that I am missing.

i am also confused about the idea since that in the procedural there is an indentation, should OOP be indented too?

thanks for your help.

Comment: It's an indentation problem. You need to be sure all your methods are indented the same amount. How long is your complete code? If it's less than 100 lines or so post the complete old (working) code here and I'll translate it to OOP.

Comment: @Novel this is my original version.  now it has another problem. 'Application' object has no attribute 'tk'.  so, if you would be so kind, I need to put that list into the grid labels by hitting the "calculate" button because that list will change value.  after this part work, I want to learn how to make it into MVC as my learning path.  thanks again.

Comment: Well If you have some complete working code than maybe posting it on Code Review might be better in this case. Also yes even writing in OOP style indention is required. Python in general is indention based code.

Answer (score 0):

We have several issues to address in your code.

Converting to OOP and using a class is a good idea but you need to understand how the class is set up.

You are trying to create an class object but this object does not inherit from any of the tkinter methods and this is why you are getting the `'Application' object has no attribute 'tk'.` error as addressed in the comments. We need to tell the class it is inheriting from a tk method and complete the **init** portion of that method.

In this case we can make the class inherit from `Tk()` and run our application from there.

```
class Application(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
```

Next you need to set up all your initial window layout. This is done from within the `def __init__(self):` section and you do not need to run a 2nd init method to get this all set up. In this section we can put all of our class attributes we will need for the code. In this case I also added your global lists and dicts as class attributes as it looks like they may be needed again as the code progresses.

The next issue we should address is the use of `self.label` in your `for` loops. This is not needed and is just extra code. Instead you can assign the label directly to the dict and then use grid on that dict key/value. Because we moved your dict into the class and set them up as attributes we need to make sure we use the `self.` prefix so the code can find the dict. The same goes for your other loops as well.

```
#------add in the weekday name labels------------------
        i=1
        for day in self.days:
            self.label_days[day]=tk.Label(self.top_frame, text=day,  fg="red", bg="snow")
            self.label_days[day].grid(row=0, column=i)
            i +=1
```

The last bit I left in but is not 100% needed.

Your last button `QUIT` does not need to link to a method and can simple have the command of `command=self.destroy` here and it will work as needed. That said I left the method `def _destroy(self):` intact to show that your methods can be written after the rest of your code because we are using a class and the class can compensate unlike doing this outside of a class where you need the function write before the code that would call it.

Here is the final example that should be a cleaner more PEP8 viable bit of code.
By PEP8 I mean formatting as well. I reduced the code to something cleaner to read as well as fixed the formatting of your variable names.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Application(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("class basic window")
        self.geometry("1000x300")
        self.config(background="LightBlue4")

        self.top_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="PaleGreen2")
        self.top_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.bottom_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="gray")
        self.bottom_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.days= ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
        self.the_list = ["North", "Central", "East", "West", "Central", "South", "North"]
        self.employees=["Truck A"]
        self.label_days = {}
        self.label_employee = {}
#-----create the grid--------------------------
        i=0
        for employee in range(len(self.employees)+1):
            for day in range(len(self.days)+1):
                label = tk.Label(self.top_frame, relief="ridge", width=13, height=3)
                label.grid(row=employee, column=day, )

                if i < len(self.the_list) and employee > 0 and day > 0 and employee + day >= 2:
                        label['text'] = str(self.the_list[i])
                        i += 1
#------add in the weekday name labels------------------
        i=1
        for day in self.days:
            self.label_days[day]=tk.Label(self.top_frame, text=day,  fg="red", bg="snow")
            self.label_days[day].grid(row=0, column=i)
            i +=1
#--------add in name labels on the side--------------
        i=1
        for employee in self.dmployees:
            self.label_employee[employee]=tk.Label(self.top_frame, text=employee,  fg="red", bg="snow")
            self.label_employee[employee].grid(row=i,column=0)
            i +=1

        tk.Button(self.bottom_frame, text="CALCULATE").grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Button(self.bottom_frame, text="QUIT", command=self._destroy).grid(row=1, column=0)

    def _destroy(self):
        self.destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Application()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to explain a few things that i need to understand.  It will take me time to be efficient on python and tkinter.                                     Going back to my original obstacle, I need to bind "if i < len(self.the_list) and employee > 0 and day > 0 and employee + day >= 2:
                        label['text'] = str(self.the_list[i])
                        i += 1" to "calculate"